# how to print/echo a number into check box using php

Tags: php

I have a table in my database called `num_ticket` where I save the total numbers of ticket, e.g. 20.

Now I am trying to `print`/`echo` the ticket number in numerical pattern like `1, 2, 3, 4 .......` to 20 into different check boxes. For example `check box 1`, `check box 2`, `check box 3`, `check box 4` ........ `checkbox 20`.

I have tried to this `<?php  print implode("\n", range(1,  $num));  ?>`.

```
<?php
        if(isset($_GET['url']))
          $url = ($_GET['url']);
               $check = "SELECT * FROM raffels  WHERE  rid ='$url' ";
                             if ($result = mysqli_query($conn,$check))
                                 $totalres = mysqli_num_rows($result);       
                            if ($totalres ==0) {
                                 echo" <center><h1>Page Not Found</h1> May be the link was broken or the post has been deleted</p></center>";
                         //header("location: 404"); 
                           exit();
                            }

                              while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                                 $title = $row['title'];
                                 $price = number_format($row['amount']);
                                 $image = $row['image'];
                                 $num = $row['num_ticket'];


     $post.='<li class="seat col-xs-1 col-sm-1">
            <input type="checkbox" class="alterbutton" name="sport" 
                onchange="myFunction()" value="12" id="12" />
             <label for="12">'. implode("\n", range(1,  $num)) .'</label>    
             </li> ';

              }                       


     ?>
```

How can I make it to print each number on different check box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a loop to output those check boxes/numbers. Take your `$post .=` bit of code, and put it into a `for` loop (since you are outputting numbers starting at 1, make sure you offset the initial starting number of the loop to 1 instead of the typical 0).

```
for ($i=1; $i<=$num; $i++)
{
    $post.='<li class="seat col-xs-1 col-sm-1">
        <input type="checkbox" class="alterbutton" name="sport" 
            onchange="myFunction()" value="' . $i . '" id="sport_checkbox_' . $i . '" />
        <label for="sport_checkbox_' . $i . '">' . $i . '</label>    
        </li> ';
}
```

I noticed that you had "12" written in some of the attributes, so I changed those to the `$i` value. I also prepended "sport_checkbox_" to the `id` attribute, to make it clearer. A single number for an ID can cause headaches down the road if you were to expand the scope of your page.

P.s. Be very very careful about what you feed directly into a query, such as `$_GET['url']`. You should pass any user-supplied values to your query via a `prepared statement` to prevent SQL injections.

Comment: Thanks a million, this fixed my issues +1